# How to access keys in Context

Tags: go

**FIRST EXAMPLE**:

I'm using `chi` router (github.com/go-chi/chi) and this simple default code:

```
func main() {
    router := chi.NewRouter()

    router.Group(func(subrouter chi.Router) {

        subrouter.Use(AddContext)

        subrouter.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            ctx := r.Context()

            routeContext := ctx.Value("RouteContext")
            test := ctx.Value("myContextTestKey")

            fmt.Printf("ctx: %+v\n", ctx)
            fmt.Printf("routeContext: %+v\n", routeContext)
            fmt.Printf("test: %+v\n", test)
        })
    })

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + Port,
        Handler: router,
    }
    err := srv.ListenAndServe()
    CheckErr(err)
}

func AddContext(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "myContextTestKey", "myContextTestValue")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

This is my context if I `Printf` it:

```
ctx: context.Background

.WithValue(&http.contextKey{name:"http-server"}, &http.Server{Addr:":3000", Handler:(*chi.Mux)(0xc0002f8840), TLSConfig:(*tls.Config)(0xc000430300), ReadTimeout:0, ReadHeaderTimeout:0, WriteTimeout:0, IdleTimeout:0, MaxHeaderBytes:0, TLSNextProto:map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler){"h2":(func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler))(0x78b450)}, ConnState:(func(net.Conn, http.ConnState))(nil), ErrorLog:(*log.Logger)(nil), disableKeepAlives:0, inShutdown:0, nextProtoOnce:sync.Once{m:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, done:0x1}, nextProtoErr:error(nil), mu:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, listeners:map[*net.Listener]struct {}{(*net.Listener)(0xc0001222b0):struct {}{}}, activeConn:map[*http.conn]struct {}{(*http.conn)(0xc000149680):struct {}{}, (*http.conn)(0xc000160460):struct {}{}}, doneChan:(chan struct {})(nil), onShutdown:[]func(){(func())(0x7972c0)}})

.WithValue(&http.contextKey{name:"local-addr"}, &net.TCPAddr{IP:net.IP{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1}, Port:3000, Zone:""}).WithCancel.WithCancel

.WithValue(&chi.contextKey{name:"RouteContext"}, &chi.Context{Routes:(*chi.Mux)(0xc0002f8840), RoutePath:"", RouteMethod:"GET", RoutePatterns:[]string{"/"}, URLParams:chi.RouteParams{Keys:[]string(nil), Values:[]string(nil)}, routePattern:"/", routeParams:chi.RouteParams{Keys:[]string(nil), Values:[]string(nil)}, methodNotAllowed:false})

.WithValue("myContextTestKey", "myContextTestValue")
```

**SECOND EXAMPLE**:

Using github.com/volatiletech/authboss I'm trying to access context using this code:

```
router.Use(ab.LoadClientStateMiddleware)

router.Group(func(subrouter chi.Router) {
    subrouter.Use(authboss.Middleware2(ab, 1, 1))
    subrouter.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if user := r.Context().Value("user"); user != nil {
            fmt.Println(user.(auth.User))
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Still nil")
        }
    }
}
```

and as you can see from this pic:

[image: debugging]

the key `user` is there.

**QUESTIONS**:

1) **Why I can't access it with `r.Context().Value("user")? Why always`nil`?**

2) Why I got `nil` for `routeContext` and got correctly `myContextTestValue` for `test` var?

3) **How to read other keys in my Context?**

**Note**: I don't have this problem just with `chi router`, I cannot understand how to access keys in context. I know I have to use in `.Value()` the same type of the key but how to know the type before?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it simply "How do I know the underlying type of the value returned by `.Value()`?"  If so, the answer usually is: You put the value there, so you should know what you put there.

Comment: Dear @Flimzy I edited. I think now is more clear.

Comment: You must pass the correct key value, which is most of the time not a plain string but a pointer. [RouteContext](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/44932d207a10cd2f26b06095a61843c9807188ea/context.go#L12), [http-server](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9e277f7d554455e16ba3762541c53e9bfc1d8188/src/net/http/server.go#L237), [local-addr](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9e277f7d554455e16ba3762541c53e9bfc1d8188/src/net/http/server.go#L243). ie `ctx.Value(chi.RouteCtxKey)`

Comment: @mkopriva and what about access to: `&chi.contextKey{name:"RouteContext"}` value?

Comment: If you got `nil`, that means that key wasn't set. And your code doesn't set it, so that would seem to make sense.

Comment: @Flimzy but I can see it in debug, see pic: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/41120635/50558958-7e2ce080-0cf2-11e9-9572-f255529bbfc2.png. In this case I got `nil` for `"user"` value. Why?

Comment: @FredHors `&chi.contextKey{name:"RouteContext"} != "RouteContext"`, have you already tried  `ctx.Value(chi.RouteCtxKey)` as I've pointed out in the previous comment?

Comment: @mkopriva I updated question which the real problem I had. Can you read and answer that so I can choose your answer?

Comment: @FredHors https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss/blob/db25c5e30be65b7a9003e28680d9b301f53f83ab/context.go#L13 pass that to ctx.Value. Simply passing `"user"` won't match because it's a different string *type*.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot. It now works. Is there a way to understand immediately these types? Do you see this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZEvD.png It is difficult from here to understand, right?

Comment: @FredHors I don't think there is anything in the std lib that would help you but I'm fairly certain that if you look on github you'll find some "object dumper" code that you can use. Alternatively with the help of the `reflect` package you should be able to implement something yourself. That said, I don't think any of that is necessary for this specific problem because most, if not all, packages that use context to store values and expect the client code to retrieve those values will export the keys for the client or will export functions that the client can call to retrieve the values.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot. ♥

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem with a different library. Similarly, I attached a screen shot of me inspecting `context` while debugging the code to show that we were running into a similar problem.

[image: ctx object]

Note that `.val` in the `Expression` input box is in red indicating that it is not a property defined on `context` (even though it exists and is accessible by `.val`).
[image: ctx val property]

[image: ctx key]

[image: ctx val]

Like you said, the key and property clearly exist, and I can access it while debugging. But I cannot access it via the code

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@matryer/context-keys-in-go-5312346a868d) to clarify the confusion.

Essentially, any time a package handles context and adds a property to it, the key for that property should not be a string, but a string type (that is not exported). This prevents key collision with other packages that use context. For example,

```
package some_library
type some_key string
```

```
package my_package
type some_key string
```

A variable of type `some_key` will be different between the two packages.
(See the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) for more info)

So if you want to actually access the key in context for that type, instead of importing that key from the package and using it to access the property in context, packages will instead have a method that you can import that allows you to retrieve the property. This is some code from `google.golang.org/grpc/metadata` as an example on how to access the [metadata property](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/metadata/metadata.go#L147) on context using a [method](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/metadata/metadata.go#L180) that they provide:

```
package metadata

type mdIncomingKey struct{}

func FromIncomingContext(ctx context.Context) (md MD, ok bool) {
    md, ok = ctx.Value(mdIncomingKey{}).(MD)
    return
}
```

And if you were to try to access the key in your own package,

```
package my_package

import "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"

// yes
md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)

// no, but will be accessible this way while debugging the code
// md := ctx.Value("key")

// no, but will be accessible this way while debugging the code
// md := ctx.Value("val")
```